# Пролагивает страница при загрузке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

При загрузки страницы, иногда происходит такой пролаг, она растягивается, как буд-то у нее ширина 200%, потом все становится нормальным. 
Возможные причины:

1. в начале страницы подгружается блок с svg

   ```
   <div style="
       position: absolute; 
       visibility: hidden; 
       display:none; 
       width: 0; 
       height: 0;">
   <svg></svg>
   </div>
   ```

> Чтобы подключать svg иконки через use.

2. Страница имеет вот такую структуру

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  background: #2f3234;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 -11px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-self: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.column-1,
.column-3 {
  padding: 0 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.column-2 {
  order: inherit;
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column-1"></div>
        <div class="column-2"></div>
        <div class="column-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="key"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
```

Возможно ли пролаг из-за этих стилей?

3)Страница отдается через handelbars возможен ли пролаг из-за него?

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что с такими примером и описанием, можно, что-то понять и получить внятный ответ и помощь.... У меня смутные подозрения, что причина проблемы `SVG`...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте явно задать ширину для body:

```
body {
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```